# How can I store a string in a varbinary(max) column using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I store a string in a varbinary(max) column?

I'm havig trouble in the convertion process
i'm doing this:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into " + bdcombo.Text + ".dbo.nomes (id, nome) values (@id, @nome)";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlcon;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nome", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 20).Value = Convert.ToSByte(textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Why are you using `varbinary` to store strings?

Comment: why do you want to store a string in a varbinary column?? Can't you store it in varchar one

Comment: what problem you're facing any error? exception?

Comment: @Oded I have a situation where I'm storing text documents of different formats (pdf, docx) in a varbinary(max) column for semantic search.  Sometimes my document is just raw text, so this is the way to handle that.

Comment: @Scott - PDF is **not** text (nor is docx, which is, technically XML, which yes, technically is a textual format).

Comment: @Oded my point is that "needing to store pdf, docx and raw strings in the aame column for full text indexing" is a valid use case for putting a string into a varbinary column.  Your comment seems to suggest that there does not exist such a use case.

Comment: @Scott - I am asking why the OP is storing **strings** (not text, not PDFs, not whole documents), in a `varbinary` column. The type of `bdcombo.Text` is `string` - it *cannot* be a random byte stream (which, yes, a PDF may contain).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to store a string, use [n]varchar(max).

If you **must** use varbinary(max), then to get the bytes you must use an encoding, for example:

```
byte[] theBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString);
```

and later:

```
string theString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(theBytes);
```

(when reading)